# Angular symlinked module isn't added to the compiled javascript output

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, webpack

I am creating a test application with angular to test my angular library. When I symlink to the library in my `package.json` and set `preserveSymlinks` to true in the `angular.json` like this:

package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@org/library": "file:../v6/library/libs",
  }
}
```

angular.json

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "application-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "local": {
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.lcl.json",
              "main": "src/main.ts",
              "preserveSymlinks": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

tsconfig.lcl.json (`"preserveSymlinks": true` in the extended file)

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ]
}
```

I then get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')

And that is because angular/webpack is not including the `@org/library` in the final js file:

```js
/***/ 9760:
/*!*******************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/@org/library/button/src/index.ts ***!
  \*******************************************************/
/***/ (() => {


/***/ }),

/***/ 2583:
/*!*****************************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/@org/library/button/src/lib/button/button.component.ts ***!
  \*****************************************************************************/
/***/ (() => {


/***/ }),
```

What I did to fix this, is to include them in the `tsconfig.lcl.json`:

```json
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/@org/library/*/src/index.ts",
    "./node_modules/@org/library/*/src/**/*.component.ts",
    "./node_modules/@org/library/*/src/**/*.model.ts",
    "./node_modules/@org/library/*/src/**/*.service.ts",
    "./node_modules/@org/library/*/src/**/*.directive.ts",
    "./node_modules/@org/library/*/src/**/*.pipe.ts",
    "./node_modules/@org/library/*/src/**/*.module.ts",
  ],
}
```

This removes the error but now I get hundreds of warnings saying:

> [webpack-dev-server] WARNING
> /test/node_modules/@org/library/button/src/lib/button.component.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
> Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

How can I fix this so I don't have to use the `"include"` part within the tsconfig? The entry point is already there using the `"files"` options. Shouldn't it automatically include the dependency file(s)?